# To + [verb] or ing?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I want to write a sentence, but I don't know the right way to do it. I need to tell about dreams that I had(achieved dreams).

- My dreams were to study abroad, get a well-paid job and a nice wife.

or

- My dreams were studying abroad, getting a well-paid and a nice wife.

Or both are wrong?

Comment: I had those dreams. They already became reality.

Comment: Wonderful! Then, "My dreams were to study abroad, to obtain a well-paying job, and to have a nice wife."

Comment: @MarkHubbard On the premise that the speaker accomplished all those, why is only first one correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it would also be correct to write, "My dreams were studying abroad, obtaining a well-paying job, and having a nice wife." Does that help? To my ear, using the infinitives (to study, to obtain, to have) just sounds more natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to use either the infinitive or the gerund when making *lists* of things, but good style recommends you use the same for all the elements of the list:

> I like to ski, to surf, and to shoot baskets.
>
> I like skiing, surfing, and shooting baskets.

So in your example, just make sure all the elements have the same *form*:

> My dreams were to study abroad, (to) get a well-paid job and (to) have a nice wife.
>
> I dreamt of studying abroad, getting a good job, and marrying a nice woman.

You can also just list them as simple nouns (the related verbs are implied):

> I dreamed of study abroad, a good job, and a nice wife.

Side note: it's not logical to say that you dream of "marrying a nice wife" because, at the time you marry her, she's not your "wife".  Instead you say "I want to marry a nice *girl/woman* (and settle down, have kids, etc.)". However, it is fine to talk about marrying your wife in the past:

> "I married my wife in February."

or

> "I had married my wife in 2010 in a civil ceremony before a judge, but our actual *wedding* was a year later."

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences tell me you had only three dreams/desires but you no longer have them.  "My dreams are..." = you do still have them.

"...and a nice wife" presumably means "...and have/marry a nice wife" (1st sentence)/"...and having/marrying a nice wife (2nd sentence)".

In both sentences "well-paid job" should be "well-paying job" until one is no longer being paid.  The subject verb = 'to get'; not 'to pay'.  As long as you have a consistent 'to verb' + ing form before "well-paying", the sentence is correct.